# LimitTo With ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't figure out why this simple limitTo isn't working with ng-repeat; I just want a short preview of each, but I'm getting some unordered lists with > 30 list items. Any suggestions?

```
<ul ng-repeat="schema in catalog.schemas" class="col-md-10">
Schema: {{schema.schema_name}}

<li ng-repeat="table in schema.tables | limitTo: 3" class="tables-preview">
Table: {{table.table_name}}
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the schema and table data structures? If it's an object of objects it probably won't work because angular's filters are defined on arrays.

Comment: It wont work if schema.table is an object. Also if it is an array it should, just check rendered template once to make sure it is not cached.

Comment: Yep, wasn't thinking- the tables are objects, thanks guys